# Pushing view in block

Tags: ios, view, block, pushviewcontroller

I am calling a view pushing method in a completion block and it does not work, normally when i call it from another non-block method it works. I think it is related with thread but i could not work it out, what should i do?

This is my push method:

```
-(void)goToVenues{
 venuesList *venuesList = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VenuesList"];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:venuesList animated:YES];
}
```

And this is completion block:

```
    [FSOAuth requestAccessTokenForCode:accessCode
                              clientId:clientID
                     callbackURIString:callbackURI
                          clientSecret:clientSecret
                       completionBlock:^(NSString *authToken, BOOL requestCompleted, FSOAuthErrorCode errorCode) {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:authToken forKey:@"token"];
            [self goToVenues];

 }];
```

Comment: You check if the completionBlock is run on the main thread using `[NSThread isMainThread]`

Comment: it returns 1 but still does not call my push method

Answer (score 3):

Move your method call to the main thread and don't forget to syncronize the user defaults after modifying it, like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:authToken forKey:@"token"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] syncronize];
    [self goToVenues];
});
```

Comment: [NSThread isMainThread] returns 1, but still does not call goToVenues method.